# Xampp php showing blank page

Tags: php, xampp

I installed xampp and it all seemed to be working fine. Today the http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ is showing only a blank page. I thought it was caused by the following warning I got:

XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...Warning: World-writable config file '/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf' is ignored

So I did:

chmod 644 /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf

Thinking it would fix it. I restarted xampp, the view on http://localhost/dashboard/ works just fine, the warning is gone, but the php page at http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ is still just blank. How can I fix this? Any help would be deeply appreciated

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display?rq=1 and edit `/phpmyadmin/index.php` and `php.ini` to hopefully see a relevant error message.

Answer (score 0):

can be an issue due to memory from cache. a few suggestions :

- clear browsing data
- go into php.ini file and fix the memory limit by changing the syntax to 1GB or up the memory

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by just doing a reinstall, don't know exactly what went wrong the first time but now it works.